# Sticking nodes to SkSpriteNode after enlargement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

**Problem**

As of right now, I've just realised a pretty major design flaw in my application..

So, the problem is:

A rifle shot is fired, and lands based on no trajectory as of right now, I'm toying with the idea. However, the bullets land and their marks are left as nodes.

```
-(void)applyShot:(int) posX with:(int) posY {
    SKSpriteNode *impact = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
    impact.zPosition = 1;
    impact.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    impact.position = CGPointMake(posX , posY);
    [backgroundImage addChild:impact];
}
```

And posX / posY are sent this way.

```
//Find difference between centre and background moved distance.
CGPoint positionNow = CGPointMake(backgroundImage.position.x, backgroundImage.position.y);
CGPoint positionPrev = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

float xdiff = positionNow.x - positionPrev.x;
float ydiff = positionNow.y - positionPrev.y;

//Calculate ydrop
int newYDrop = yDrop * 10;
//

CGPoint newPositionOne = CGPointMake(0.5 - xdiff, 0.5 - ydiff);
newPositionOne = CGPointMake((newPositionOne.x + [self myRandom:15 withFieldLower:-15]), (newPositionOne.y - newYDrop));

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(secondsDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self applyShot:newPositionOne.x with:newPositionOne.y];
});
```

Which seems to work fine, until I started toying with zoom.

Now, this application basically is a 1080p image for the reticle, and the background enlarges to give the (zoom) effect, then the background is touch-dragged/inverted to give the reticle moving effect.

Then I managed to get it to fire exactly where the crosshair was, which was good.. Then I started toying with zoom and noticed this.

[image][image]

So if it's not too easy to notice, the (bullet hits) are the grey marks, however, when you enlarge the backgroundImage they aren't tied to it. so they remain the same spread.

**Solution**

Now what I need is to either,

- A: tie the nodes to the backgroundImage
- B: enlarge the spread to the same factor as the enlargement.

But I'm pretty confused at how to achieve this.

**Additional problem**

When calibrating the drop, the drop will remain a burden no matter of the zoom as of right now. so if it's a 1 mil-dot drop on 6x zoom, it's also a 1 mil-dot drop at 10x zoom or 1x zoom ( I keep saying zoom when I mean enlargement )

How can I achieve a calibration for drop intensity no matter what enlargement the background image is at?

Thanks for reading and confusing yourself with my dire problems, it's appreciated!

**What I've Tried**

saving the children to a mutable array, then recreating them after a zoom change;

```
//recreate children
[backgroundImage removeAllChildren];
for (int i=0; i < [shotsHitX count]; i++) {

    double posX = ([shotsHitX[i] doubleValue] / 5) * rifleZoom;
    double posY = ([shotsHitY[i] doubleValue] / 5) * rifleZoom;

    SKSpriteNode *impact = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
    impact.zPosition = 1;
    impact.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    impact.position = CGPointMake(posX , posY);

    [shotsHitX addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:posX]];
    [shotsHitY addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:posY]];

    [backgroundImage addChild:impact];
}
//end recreate children
```

Crash with memory error.

***not so good at this!***

```
[backgroundImage removeAllChildren];
for (int i=0; i < [shotsHitX count]; i++) {

    double posX = ([shotsHitX[i] doubleValue] / 5) * rifleZoom;
    double posY = ([shotsHitY[i] doubleValue] / 5) * rifleZoom;

    SKSpriteNode *impact = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
    impact.zPosition = 1;
    impact.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    impact.position = CGPointMake(posX , posY);

    [backgroundImage addChild:impact];
}
//end recreate children
```

Works, however, now It doesn't just seem quite right..

I think the problem is when the initial zoom goes in it works, then when it reverts it's mixing zoom shots in the array with old shots.. Here we go again, **MORE ARRAYS**.

```
    //recreate children
    [backgroundImage removeAllChildren];
    for (int i=0; i < [shotsHitRem count]; i+= 2) {

        double posX = ([shotsHitRem[i] doubleValue] / 5) * rifleZoom;
        double posY = ([shotsHitRem[i+1] doubleValue] / 5) * rifleZoom;

        SKSpriteNode *impact = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] size:CGSizeMake(2, 2)];
        impact.zPosition = 1;
        impact.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        impact.position = CGPointMake(posX , posY);
        [backgroundImage addChild:impact];

        //add olds m4
        if ([shotsHitM4 count] > 0) {
            posX = ([shotsHitM4[i] doubleValue] / 2) * rifleZoom;
            posY = ([shotsHitM4[i+1] doubleValue] / 2) * rifleZoom;
            impact.position = CGPointMake(posX, posY);
            [backgroundImage addChild:impact];
        }
    }
    //end recreate children
```

Now I crash attempting to add a sknode which already has a parent

Confusing as it should removeAllChildren before looping

Comment: Figured the calibrating fix, just multiplied the drop by the zoom distance.. I think I'm onto something here..

Comment: @rakeshbs They are added as children if I'm not mistaken :O? The problem is when it scales, they do not.

`[backgroundImage addChild:impact];`

Answer (score 1):

Well after some major messing around

```
[backgroundImage setScale:rifleZoom];
```

Programming is my favourite, oh yeah.. Five hours, Oh yeah.. For one line, oh yeah!

I wasn't scaling before, I was creating a new cgsize. and that was my problem.

I now have the issue of scaling and trying to render a new centrepoint as it still remembers the centrepoint of scale = 1 and scale = 2, nightmare.